# It's fast to build and update a static site or a dynamic site?

Tags: html, performance, build, web

Good day, everyone!

I'm currently building 2 sites: one of them is my 'personal website' that will contain contact information, current and finished projects. (Like a presentation card, you know what I'm talking about!).

The other one it's a site regarding a tool that I'm currently developing: I want to make 3-4 section with classic things about a software: what it is, what it does, news about developments, a FAQ section and a download page.

Now, the problem is: I don't want to waste time with such 'silly' website. I want make it fast and update it easily.

I've got 2 ways in my mind:

1) Create a dynamic site (php) that will 'build' pages from a database that contains all things like finished projects, news feed and so on. I have to create the backend for content insertion, but once i've done it I can insert new content in few seconds.

2) Build a site based on static pages (classic html) filled MANUALLY with new content (like the weekly news feed); isn't much 'professional', it's much more fast to grow up but can be difficult to insert new content (Every time I want to make a news I have to write the title in an html tag, bold content with  tag and so on) and move manually the old news to another page. Maybe exist external tool to help me doing that?

I always thought that static webpage aren't used even for site that 'allows' new content being updated often (once a week) but I found that isn't completely true: LOT of site that I like (medium popularity software sites) it's just a bunch of text on a static page.

I guess that isn't a smart thing waste time build a nice site for a poor developed software, isn't it?

Also, isn't kind of newbie build a site with such an old way?
What tool can I use for fast 'formatting' html news text?

Any suggestion for creating these website with fewest time spent?

Answer (score 0):

When I develop websites, I use a basic template: a "toolbar" or "navbar" at the top of the page and an iframe tag that contains the content and pages browsed. You can learn how [Joomla!](http://joomla.org) and [Wordpress](http://Wordpress.org) platforms work and see the idea behind it: a group of files build an html file from data stored inside XML files (either in physical disk or in a database). Those files and classes build and render those pages until you get what you see in a static (sometimes dynamic with JavaScript/jQuery) page/file. Open-Source is a great thing - the human kind must use it wisely.

Answer (score 0):

I will also recommend using JSON or some other database to get the needed code and append it to the body. I use `XMLHttpRequest()` to get code inside json, i then parse it get the html string and append it to the body of my website. It works well for me.‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎